# Remove a line from a file in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

Say if I had a file list like so:

```
Example1.txt
Example2.txt
Example3.txt
DeleteMe.txt
```

Is it possible to remove the "DeleteMe.txt" from the file list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`findstr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) is similar to `grep` - and includes an option to give only lines that don't match the given pattern:

```
type in.txt | findstr /v /c:"deleteme.txt" > out.txt
```

Comment: `findstr /v/b/e/i /c:"deleteme.txt"` <--- this findstr term might be better so that `pleasedonotdeleteme.txt` doesn't also get nuked.

Comment: You also need the /L option so that `.` is treated as a literal instead of a regex wildcard! You can use `\X` instead of `\B\E`, and you can combine the options: `findstr /vxilc:"deleteme.txt" >out.txt`